# Loading a matrix of float numbers from a file

Tags: python, string

I have some data like,

```
  1  2  3  4
  3  5  6  7
  2  8  9  10
```

and my code is

```
    #!/bin/usr/python
    file=open("fer.txt","r")
    M=[]
    P=[]
    K=[]
    def particle(M,P,K):
        for line in file:
            y=line.split()
            M.append(y)
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(4):
                P.append(float(M[i][j]))
            K.append(P)
        return K
   print(particle(M,P,K))
```

and then I got

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 2.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0], [1.0, 
2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 2.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 
4.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 2.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]]
```

but I ahould have or I want something like this,

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,], [3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0],[ 2.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]]
```

Edit for duplicate flag: I dont see how its a duplicate question of mine. I am asking different thing also I am trying to understand why my code doesnt work.

Comment: ...why is the title of the question asking about string->float conversion? That's the one part of your code that actually works correctly.

Comment: I couldnt convert them in a form that I wanted

Comment: I think your problem is that P is the same object every time you append it to K

Comment: yes but why it acts like that I have a range of j 4 so that shouldnt have happened ?

Comment: With `K.append(P)` you append one and the same list instance to the matrix multiple times. The range has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Using an iteration. You can use `map` to convert all elements of list to float.

**Ex:**

```
res = []
with open(filename2) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        res.append(map(float, line.split()))
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0], [2.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]]
```

Comment: A slightly different code: https://gist.github.com/arsho/78c1dd9a8ee866d422103049f853555e

Comment: Thanks for this comment its really simply and worked

Comment: but I still didnt understand  my code doesnt work

Comment: Please accept ans if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

first answer is correct but if you want in a one liner:

---

```
#sample.txt content: 
1  2  3  4
3  5  6  7
2  8  9  10
```

---

```
#code:

In [12]: d = open('sample.txt').readlines()
    ...: result =  [map(float, x.split()) for x in d]
```

---

## output:

```
In [13]: result
Out[13]: [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0], [2.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]]
```